# Sql 2005 problem in set up

Tags: sql-server

When I setup sql2005 this problem appear Minimum Hardware Requirement (Warning) Messages Minimum Hardware Requirement

The current system does not meet the minimum hardware requirements for this SQL Server release. For detailed hardware and software requirements, see the readme file or SQL Server Books Online.

and I continued setup but I couldnot found sql management studio tools in start menue

Comment: are you sure the installation was completed, or did it abort because of the hardware constraints problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the minimum hardware requirements are only a *warning*, thus it shouldn't prevent you from installing sql server.  Are you sure you selected to install the client tools?  did you do a DVD or CD media install?  I think with the CD the client tools are on the second CD for 2005.

Follow [these steps](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/913967) to add the client tools to your existing install.